# Unable to resolve dependency for

Tags: java, android, sdk

Подключаю этот SDK https://github.com/KosyanMedia/Aviasales-Android-SDK. С последней зависимостью не хочет компилироваться, без нее все нормально. В чем может быть проблема?
build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://android.aviasales.ru/repositories/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.bruimafia.ticketsdiscount"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'ru.aviasales:aviasalesSdk:2.1.16-sdk'
    implementation 'ru.aviasales.template:aviasalesSdkTemplate:2.1.16'
    implementation 'ru.aviasales.template:appodeallib:2.1.16'
}
```

Ошибки

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ru.aviasales.template:appodeallib:2.1.16. 
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ru.aviasales.template:appodeallib:2.1.16.  
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve ru.aviasales.template:appodeallib:2.1.16.
```

Comment: Откуда вы взяли, что последняя зависимость вообще нужна? В документации о ней ничего не сказано.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja сказано в конце, нужна для подключения Appodeal ads (монетизации)

Comment: В демо проекте они ее используют как модуль, не как внешнюю библиотеку. Но можете попробовать все указанные там репозитории. https://github.com/KosyanMedia/Aviasales-Android-SDK/blob/master/ads_simple_demo/build.gradle